# ZenCart Lost file location

Tags: php, file, zen-cart

over a year ago, I was using ZenCart, and an incredible novice at any form of coding. I set up an EZ-Page for a really complex piece of PHP that I wrote, and saved it. That page still works today properly (minus a few bugs which I know how to fix now) - however, I wish to migrate it over to a working site. Unfortunately, I can't find where the actual PHP code is that was written.

Viewing the EZ-Page in the editor shows no link destination, and no content

The URL is Site.com/index.php?main_page=pagename

any idea where in the FTP or where I could recover this code?!?!

(I have been searching for 45+ minutes now...)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

older versions of ZenCart place these files under:

```
<ROOT>/includes/templates/<YOUR TEMPLATE>/templates
```